# How can I align text inside an <li> element in a navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me align the text inside `li`? I tried `vertical-align: middle;` but it doesn't seem to work. 
Here is my code.

```css
#menu {
  clear: both;
  border-color: #004F7B;
  background-color: #414446;
  border-width: 1px 0px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#menu .menu-content {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
#menu ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu li a {
  color: #E5EAED;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 1px 0px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
#menu li.logo {
  margin: 0px 190px 0px -40px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom-header">
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="menu-content">
        <ul>
          <li class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Racing Games">Racing</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Bike Games">Bike</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Car Parking Games">Car Parking</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an image for reference:

[image: reference image]

Comment: Do you want to centre horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Here is the complete guide to centering in CSS: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Whenever something doesn't work, I reference this. In your case I would suggest working with padding-top and padding-bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand from the image you provided, you are trying to maintain equal distance between text and you have given width 200px to li and that is why you text is not aligning properly. Try below css , hope this will help you.

```css
  #menu {
      clear: both;
      border-color: #004F7B;
      background-color: #414446;
      border-width: 1px 0px 0px;
      border-style: solid;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 120px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1000;
  }

 #menu .menu-content {
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 980px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     color: white;
     line-height: 70px;
     font-size: 1.5em;
}

#menu li {
     float: left;
     width: auto;
     text-align: center;
}

#menu ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li a {
   color: #E5EAED;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
   float: none;
   display: inline;
   padding: 0px 30px;
   height: 60px;
   margin: 10px 1px 0px;
   line-height: 60px;
}

#menu li.logo {
   margin: 0px 190px 0px -40px;
   width: 180px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom-header">
   <div id="menu">
     <div class="menu-content">
       <ul>
         <li class="logo"><img src="" alt=""></li>
         <li><a href="#" title="Racing Games">Racing</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" title="Bike Games">Bike</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" title="Car Parking Games">Car Parking</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Oh my god thanks you so much! This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using display:flex

```css
#menu {
  border-color: #004F7B;
  background-color: #414446;
  border-width: 1px 0px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  
}
#menu .menu-content {
   
} 
.menu-content ul {
 display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.menu-content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:25px;
 
}
#menu li a {
   color: #E5EAED;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li.logo {
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom-header">
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="menu-content">
        <ul>
          <li class="logo">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Racing Games">Racing</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Bike Games">Bike</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Car Parking Games">Car Parking</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for you recommendation but It seems that flex has some issues with older browsers.

Comment: this link could be of helpful to u for flex-box browser suppert https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/